# How to deal with decimal operation error?

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a scaling function for values, which looks something like this:

```
r = a/b*c;
```

Where r,a,b,c are decimals.

Most of the times, it works correctly, but sometimes I get something like this:

```
1.5M/3.09785668M*3.09785668M => 1.5000000000000000000000000001M
```

This is a problem for me because over time in my calculations, the error escalates.

What is the best way to detect and remove this kind of errors?

Comment: Multiply first then divide

Comment: Any identified specific times when this is happening for ex: very large value etc.? Also if you try `r = a/(b*c)` or `r = (a/b)*c` (based on your calculation requirement), check what happens in those scenarios.

Comment: @SivaGopal: should be r=a/(b/) or r = (a*c)/b - * & / have same precedence so are evaluated left to right.

Comment: @TimSchmelter multiply than divide works in this case, but is there a guarantee that it will yield correct value all of the time?

Comment: @ArsenZahray - whenever you work with data types with a limited amount of precision, there's no guarantee that "all of the time" you can find an ordering of operations that avoids error. You *could* switch to data types that offer unlimited precision, but that tends to be a fairly costly decision (performance wise).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Need to choose between Performance Vs Accuracy as usual !!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever which types do you have in mind?

Comment: @PaulF [This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280039/operator-precedence-in-c-sharp) has one of possible clean ways to calculation!

Comment: @ArsenZahray - so long as you promise to stay in the realm of the rationals, you could use e.g. [`Rational`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.common.rational(v=vs.93).aspx) from the Microsoft Solver Foundation, which in turn is using a `BigInteger` type.

Comment: @SivaGopal: I think you missed my point - r = a/b * c => r=a/(b/c) - OP was wondering why dividing by one number & then multiplying by another didn't correct cancel - r = a/(b*c) would not be expected to cancel. Just noticed my original post had a typo - missing the c in the first rearrangement.

Comment: @ArsenZahray: you need to understand that there are numbers that it is impossible to represent in a digital format - you need to decide on an acceptable degree of precision. Decimals give a better precision than doubles at the expense of range - so while Tim's original comment worked in this instance, you may find in other circumstances that multiplying first overflows the decimal range, so division first is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Detect**

```
r = a/b*c;
Debug.Assert(r*b/c == a, "Not good");
```

**Avoid** non-terminating sub-result but still be vulnerable to precision loss and non-terminating end results

```
r = a*c/b;
```

So basically, the two kinds of problematic sub-results are (1) finite precision loss and (2) non-terminating numbers

(1):

```
var loss1 = 1.000000000000000000001m * 1.000000000000000000001m;
// should be 1.000000000000000000002000000000000000000001m
// will be be 1.000000000000000000002m
```

(2):

```
var loss2 = 1m/3m;
// should be 0.333333333333333333333.. infinite line of 3
// will be be 0.3333333333333333333333333333M
```

The first kind can happen on multiplication and division, the second kind only on division. The first kind can be fixed by adding precision, the second kind can only ever be fixed by carrying the fraction as is instead of trying to create a single real number of any limited precision.